# How to pick the correct R-Pi

Tags: wifi, hardware, mysql

I have a requirement to build a monitoring device with a display. The main conditions are:

- Need a MySQL database
- Need Internet connectivity via WiFi
- Capable of reading MODBUS slave device, and other analog/digital inputs
- Webserver which serves the dashboard page
- Need single display
- Mouse and Keyboard

What is the minimum Raspberry Pi configuration I can choose so that I can have all the above functionalities?

Comment: Welcome. Any model except the Pico can do this -- although none of them can read analog signals directly, you would need an ADC.  Also, the Zero models have significant restrictions WRT USB inputs, you probably want to avoid that.